# Is there a way with CSS to add space between the cursor, and the placeholder text in an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

My question relates to a bug found on an earlier version of Firefox for OSX (37.0.2), which I have a screenshot of here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzK0G.png

Is there any way with css to move the placeholder's first character away from where the cursor initially sits?

The page is an Angular app, which sometimes doesn't play well with Firefox, I've heard.

I've tried adding text-indent, and padding-left to moz-placeholder, but that moves the cursor along with the placeholder text.

I've also built a bit of JS to prepend a space to placeholder text, within all versions of Firefox, but I'd love to avoid having to do this.

Comment: I know it's not too good solution but why don't you try placeholder="  Placeholer" in the input?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid, as the issue doesn't appear in other browsers, but thank you for your idea!

Comment: using https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/ apply padding-left. i also like to apply something like `:focus ::-moz-placeholder{color: transparent;}`

Comment: does the `:first-letter` selector work on placeholder text? i haven't tried it. just a thought. link to docs: [http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-formatted-line](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-formatted-line)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to either generate all placeholders with a leading space, as previously stated, or simply use `::-moz-placeholder { font-style: italic; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use the **white-space: pre;** property in CSS which doesn't collapse spaces, to display leading spaces in a placeholder text.

*For example* : If you are working with **Angular** multi-select dropdown then, you shall make use of a similar code shown below to render leading spaces in a placeholder text.

```
<ng-select style="white-space: pre" placeholder="  Example of a placeholder with leading spaces!" [multiple]="xxxx" [formControl]="xxxx">                                                    
     <ng-option *ngFor="let x of y" [value]="x?.value">{{x?.text}}</ng-option>                                                
</ng-select>
```